# I am trying to run rviz but its showing this error

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

arpit@arpit-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1404470033.425833738]: rviz version 1.10.16
[ INFO] [1404470033.425932691]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/183151/i-am-trying-to-run-rviz-but-its-showing-this-error/) by [arpitbhateley](https://answers.ros.org/users/19466/arpitbhateley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try what is mentioned there:

http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Troubleshooting#Segfault_during_startup

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arpitbhateley](https://answers.ros.org/users/19466/arpitbhateley/) on 2014-07-09**:
I tried that but it didn't work.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-09**:
Please do not create answers for discussion or comments. Instead, either edit and append to your original post or use the comment functionality.